# solution of non linear differential second order equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

we have the following differential equation 
$$
uu''=1+(u') ^2
$$
i found that the general solution of this equation is 
$$
u=d \cosh ((x-b)/d)
$$
where $b$ and $d$ are constats.

Please how we found this general solution?

Comment: Check this [link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/BVPEvals.aspx) for an insight on how the hyperbolic cosine appears in this type of ODEs

Comment: have you checked your solution?

Comment: Are you sure that the ODE is correct? I think it should be $uu''=1+(u')^2$

Comment: Yes you are right, i edit my question. Can you help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate that equation as
$$
\frac{2u'u''}{1+u'^2}=2\frac{u'}{u}
$$
where both sides are complete differentials which integrate to
$$
\ln(1+u'^2)=\ln(u^2)+c\implies 1+u'^2=Cu^2.
$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Sorry it's no linear and i'm lost with non linear edo's. Can you help me please to continue

Comment: You just isolate $u'$, apply separation and then look up the appropriate integrals in some integral table. Or use that the identity $1+A^2=B^2$ can be parametrized as $A=\pm \sinh(v)$, $B=\pm \cosh(v)$, similar to the circle equation and trigonometric functions.

Comment: We have $+ u'^2 = C u^2$ it's not an equation of separate variables, how we can separate the variables? please

Comment: $$\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-Cu^2}}=\pm dx.$$ Or with $a^2=C$ $$au=\cosh(v),~u'=\sinh(v)=\sinh(v)\frac{v'}{a}\implies v'=a\implies v=ax+b.$$

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the second part of the answer. We have $\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-C u^1}}= dx$ ok, but what's $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-C u^1}}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$uu''=1+(u') ^2$$
Substitute $p=u'$
$$u\frac {dp}{dx}=1+p^2$$
$$u\frac {dp}{du}\frac {du}{dx}=1+p^2$$
$$u\frac {dp}{du}p=1+p^2$$
Now it's separable
$$\int \frac {pdp}{1+p^2}=\int \frac{du}u$$
It should be easy to integrate now..

---

Edit
$$p^2+1=Ku^2 \implies \int \frac {du}{\sqrt {Ku^2-1}}=\pm x+K_2$$
$$\frac {arcosh(\sqrt K u)}{\sqrt K}=x+K_2$$
Taking $cosh$ on both side
$$\sqrt K u=\cosh({\sqrt K}(x+K_2))$$
$$ \boxed{u=\frac 1 {\sqrt K}\cosh(\sqrt K x+K_2)}$$
Which is close to your formula
$$u=d \cosh ((x-b)/d) \implies d=1/\sqrt K \text{ and } -b/d=K_2$$

Comment: We obtain that $1+p^2= cu^2$ but how we deduce $u$? Please

Comment: Ok, so we obtain $\dfrac{du/dx}{\sqrt{cu^2-1}}=1$. And we integrate the two parts, but what's $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{du/dx}{\sqrt{cu^2-1}}$? Please

Comment: Then we have $arc cosh( a u)= x$ , where $c=a^2$ but how we deduce $u$? Please.

Comment: Ok so we obtain that the genaral solution is $u= \dfrac{\cosh x}{c}$ but we have to find $u$ into the form $u= d \cosh ((x-b)/d)$. How we can write the general solution into this last form? Please

Comment: I'm sorry, explain me just the last point, why we have $\cos((x-b)/d)$ please i don't understand it, whos's $K$?? Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Thank you so so much